# Hiding and showing multiple columns in Excel based on the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get columns to hide in a worksheet based on the value in a certain cell. This value could range from different name option and different columns are hidden for each possible option. I have the following code, but it doesn't seem to work all the time, and then sometimes it only hides some of the columns in the range, but not all (like if Abandonnée was in cell F7, then sometimes column H will hide and I will not be hidden). If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
If Range("F7").Value = "Abandonnée" Then  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
Else  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
End If  

If Range("F7").Value = "Abandonnée" Then  
    Columns("H:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
    Columns("H:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  

If Range("F7").Value = "Référé au spécialiste" Then  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  

If Range("F7").Value = "Référé au spécialiste" Then  
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
Else  
    Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
End If 

If Range("F7").Value = "Référé au spécialiste" Then  
    Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
    Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  

If Range("F7").Value = "En force" Then  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  

If Range("F7").Value = "En attente d'information" Then  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  

If Range("F7").Value = "En cours" Then  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If 

If Range("F7").Value = "Refusé par l'assureur" Then  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True  
Else  
    Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False  
End If  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. First unhide all the columns.
2. Then use Select Case to iterate through the conditions and hide what need to be hidden.

Like this, You will need to put in the other conditions:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Columns("G:I").Hidden = False
Select Case Range("F7")
    Case "Abandonnée"
        Columns("H:I").Hidden = True
    Case "Référé au spécialiste"
        Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Case "En force"
        Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    'Continue with all your tests
End Select


End Sub
```

If you have words that trigger hiding the same columns you can doe this as your Case statement:

```
Case "En force","Abandonnée"
     '...
```

Then when F7 is either of these two it will do what is below.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I ran into another problem when I tried using the same code but for a different range on the same sheet (i.e. replacing cell F7 with cell F10). Is there a way so that the columns can appear or be hidden automatically instead of changing through a selection @Scott

Comment: not sure I understand your question, It may be better suited as its own question where you can give examples.